# Почему table.outerheight и сумма tr.outerheight не равны

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Объясните почему. Сумма высот всех строк таблицы не равна высоте таблицы

```js
var t_h = $('.sourceTable').outerHeight();
var t_tr = 0;

$('.sourceTable').find('tr').each(function(){
 t_tr += $(this).outerHeight();
});

$('#result').find('.t-h').html(t_h);
$('#result').find('.t-tr').html(t_tr)
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 1030px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sourceTable {
    border: 0;
    width: 990px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.sourceTable > tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
  <span class="t-h"></span>
  <span class="t-tr"></span>
</div>
<table class="sourceTable">
  <tr>
    <td>11</td><td>vv</td><td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td><td>vv</td><td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td><td>vv</td><td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td><td>vv</td><td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td><td>vv</td><td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td><td>vv</td><td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td><td>vv</td><td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td><td>vv</td><td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td><td>vv</td><td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td><td>vv</td><td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td><td>vv</td><td>%%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Браузер у вас кривой, у меня 253 и 253

Comment: @alexander-lonberg Действительно в хроме значение равны(я писал в edge) Но во всех браузерах на https://jsfiddle.net/sb1pwyhf/ разное значения. На jsfiddle свой движок?

Comment: дело не в браузерах :-)

Comment: @Grundy Подскажите тогда в чем?

Comment: пишу ответ :-).

Comment: В Firefox у меня 265 и 264

Comment: @andreymal, похоже от браузеров это все-таки тоже зависит :-)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в версиях jQuery. (но не только)

В `3.3.1`, которая используется в jsfiddle при определении размеров добавлен следующий код:

```
if ( !isBorderBox && computedVal >= 0 ) {

    // offsetWidth/offsetHeight is a rounded sum of content, padding, scroll gutter, and border
    // Assuming integer scroll gutter, subtract the rest and round down
    delta += Math.max( 0, Math.ceil(
        elem[ "offset" + dimension[ 0 ].toUpperCase() + dimension.slice( 1 ) ] -
        computedVal -
        delta -
        extra -
        0.5
    ) );
}
```

За счет того, что у таблицы не стоит `box-sizing:border-box` в этом участке кода переменной `delta` присваивается `1`. Которая потом прибавляется к размеру и получается 254. В версии `3.2.1` было другое условие и лишняя 1 не добавлялась.

Проверить это можно просто подключив две версии и увидев, что для версии 3.2.1 выводится верное значение:

```js
var t_h = $('.sourceTable').outerHeight(); // 3.3.1
var t_h2 = $j('.sourceTable').outerHeight(); // 3.2.1
var t_tr = 0;

$('.sourceTable').find('tr').each(function() {
  t_tr += $(this).outerHeight();
});

$('#result').find('.t-h').html('3.3.1: ' + t_h);
$('#result').find('.t-h2').html('3.2.1: ' + t_h2);
$('#result').find('.t-tr').html(t_tr)
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 1030px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sourceTable {
  border: 0;
  width: 990px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.sourceTable>tbody>tr>td {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $j = $.noConflict();
</script>
<div id="result">
  <span class="t-h"></span><br>
  <span class="t-h2"></span><br>
  <span class="t-tr"></span>
</div>
<table class="sourceTable">
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>vv</td>
    <td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>vv</td>
    <td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>vv</td>
    <td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>vv</td>
    <td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>vv</td>
    <td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>vv</td>
    <td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>vv</td>
    <td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>vv</td>
    <td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>vv</td>
    <td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>vv</td>
    <td>%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>vv</td>
    <td>%%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Что интересно, если поставить таблице `box-sizing:border-box` на вкладке computed Chrome будет показывать высоту `254`, что опять больше суммы высот строк.

---

Кроме того в разных браузерах у таблицы разный `box-sizing` по умолчанию. Например в Chrome 72.0.3626.121 и 73.0.3683.86 - значение `content-box`

В то время как у EDGE -  значение `border-box`

Comment: я тестирую https://jsfiddle.net/sb1pwyhf/ в разных браузерах(chrome, opera, edge) и на разных версиях jquery и везде сумма не совпадает высоте

Comment: @Сергей, об этом есть в ответе: в 3.3.1 версии не совпадает именно из-за добавленного кода.

Comment: У меня ни в одной из версий не совпало. Если в остальных версиях 1 не прибавляется, то какой высоте доверять?

Comment: @Сергей, ни в одной из версий в каких браузерах? Как минимум в chrome совпадает. В EDGE всегда отличается

Comment: Что -то я проморгал на 3.2.1 действительно совпадают значения. Но в более поздних версиях опять не равны(конкретно: в рабочем проекте стоит 2.2.4(проверял на chrome 73.0.3683.86)). С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @Сергей, похоже все интереснее, и проблема на самом деле в border-collapse, если его убрать значения становятся одинаковыми, по крайней мере в хроме.